# Why the PI in the file trig.c of the GNU Scientific Library be divided in three parts?

Tags: math, floating-point, gnu, gsl, pi

In code below, why is Pi divided in three constants P1, P2 and P3? Is there some related math theory? If it is for improve the compute accuracy for r, I run the code on higher precision but without any improve than just Pi.(The code from gsl/specfunc/trig.c:576)

```c
  const double P1 = 4 * 7.85398125648498535156e-01;
  const double P2 = 4 * 3.77489470793079817668e-08;
  const double P3 = 4 * 2.69515142907905952645e-15;
  const double TwoPi = 2*(P1 + P2 + P3);

  const double y = 2*floor(theta/TwoPi);

  double r = ((theta - y*P1) - y*P2) - y*P3;
```

Comment: It should give a more accurate reduction than `fmod(theta, M_2PI)` for `theta` up to magnitude `1e+8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test program in C

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>


double mod2pi(double theta) {
  const double P1 = 4 * 7.85398125648498535156e-01;
  const double P2 = 4 * 3.77489470793079817668e-08;
  const double P3 = 4 * 2.69515142907905952645e-15;
  const double TwoPi = 2*(P1 + P2 + P3);

  const double y = 2*floor(theta/TwoPi);

  return ((theta - y*P1) - y*P2) - y*P3;
}

int main() {
  double x = 1.234e+7;

  printf("x=%.16e\nfmod  =%.16e\nmod2pi=%.16e\n",x,fmod(x,2*M_PI), mod2pi(x));

  return 0;
}
```

compared to multiprecision result using the [Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

```
RR := RealField(100);
pi := Pi(RR);
x := 1.234e+7;
n := 2*Floor(x/(2*pi));
"magma =",RR!x-n*pi;
```

with results

```
x=1.2340000000000000e+07
fmod  =6.2690732008483607e+00
mod2pi=6.2690732003673268e+00
```

and

```
magma = 6.269073200367326567623794342882040802035079748091348034188201251009459335653510999632076033999854435
```

showing that indeed the higher effort leads to more precise results.

---

### Why those constants

For some reason the developers decided to split the bits not directly of `pi/4` but based on `10*pi/4=5/2*pi` as can be seen in the next table where the top row are the bits of a long version of `5/2*pi` while the next three are binary representations of the constants multiplied by `10`.

```
111 11011010100111101000101001010101010011100001011110010110000011111010111110

111.1101101010011110100001
  0.00000000000000000000011001010101010011100001
  0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111100101100000
```

A split based on `pi/4` using 25 bits in each part is

```
0.1100100100001111110110101010001000100001011010001100001000110100110001001100

0.1100100100001111110110101
0.00000000000000000000000000100010001000010110100011
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100011010011000100110
```

and would lead to constants

```
const double P1 = 4 * 7.85398155450820922852e-01;
const double P2 = 4 * 7.94662735614792836714e-09;
const double P3 = 4 * 3.06161646971842959369e-17;
```

The idea being that integer multiples up to `2^27` of `P1,P2,P3` are exact so that the successive reductions remove the leading identical bits without losing precision. Essentially, the input argument with 53 bits mantissa gets (virtually) extended to a 75 bit mantissa by filling with zeros, and then this number gets reduces exactly by multiples of `2*pi`. Cancellation of up to 22 leading bits will not result in a loss of precision.

Comment: This style of argument reduction for trigonometric functions is known as a Cody-Waite reduction and has been used since the late 1970s. See: William J. Cody and William M. Waite. "Software manual for the elementary functions". Prentice-Hall, 1980.

Comment: Fairly recent follow-up work: [1] Jean-Michel Muller and Peter Kornerup. "Extending the Range of the Cody and Waite Range Reduction Method". 2005. [draft](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~kornerup/papers/RR.pdf). [2] Sylvie Boldo, Marc Daumas, and Ren-Cang Li. "Formally verified argument reduction with a fused multiply-add." *IEEE Transactions on Computers* 58.8 (2009): 1139-1145. [preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.3722.pdf)

Comment: I was stupid,I hadn't realized it is a funtion same as fmod,  I understand the code now, thank you for LutzL's answer. And also thanks for njuffa's recommendation, I am reading the article. This is my first question on stackoverflow, I really appreciation the platform helps me solve my problem.

Comment: The earliest printed reference I can find for the technique is: J. Y. Wang. "The evaluation of periodic functions with large input arguments." *ACM SIGNUM Newsletter* 13.4 (1978): 7-8.

Comment: If the x = 2*pi + 1, the result of mod2pi is 9.999999999999997779553950749687e-01, but the really result should be 1. Is it a week point for this method?

Comment: @Star When you say `pi` presumably you are referring to the `double` number closest to the mathematical π? If so, the result you see is a consequence of the difference between this machine PI versus the mathematical π. The point of the Cody-Waite reduction used here is to effectively reduce by mathematical π, *within a certain range* of inputs `theta`.

Comment: @Star: While computing `x=2*pi+1` you lose the last bit of the mantissa of `pi` which accounts for the error in the reduction of about `2.2e-16`.

Comment: @LutzL I don't see how this applies. Consider: `pi` = `0x1.921fb54442d180p+1`; `2*pi` = `0x1.921fb54442d180p+2`; `2*pi+1` = `0x1.d21fb54442d180p+2`.

Comment: Consider then that the reduction in `mod2pi` is by a different, more precise approximation of `pi`.

Comment: @LutzL That's what I stated four comments up, in reply to Star's comment :-)